# How to get the range of elements in a list scheme?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

So currently, I have the following list:

```
'(1 2 3 4 5 6)
```

How do I obtain a sublist given a start and end indices? 
So, input [1:3] return a list with the value '(2 3 4)

Comment: Do you just want the second and third elements, or do you want to specify a sublist of an input list? And if so, how do you want to specify the sublist: by indices, by first index and number of elements,...?

Comment: I just saw that you changed the requirement while I was writing an answer; a heads-up would have been nice. IAC, are you sure that this is how you want to specify a sublist? It is pretty common for things to work differently; e.g., in Python a slice [1:3] would give you the elements at indices 1 and 2, but not 3.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write your own procedure to do this in plain old Scheme. Both of the below solutions will work in any of R4RS, R5RS, R6RS, or R7RS Standard Scheme.

---

## A Recursive Solution

---

A recursive solution might take a list `xs` and two indices `a` and `b` as arguments. If `a` and `b` are equal, then the empty list `'()` should be returned. If `a` is zero, then the first element of the list should be `cons`ed onto the rest of the sublist. Otherwise the sublist of the rest of `xs`, with `a` and `b` diminished by one should be returned.

```
(define (sublist xs a b)
  (cond ((= a b) '())
        ((zero? a)
         (cons (car xs) (sublist (cdr xs) a (- b 1))))
        (else
         (sublist (cdr xs) (- a 1) (- b 1)))))
```

```
> (sublist '(1 2 3 4 5 6) 1 3)
(2 3)
```

Note that when `a` is zero, the first element of the list `xs` is kept (added to the resulting sublist), but in this case the last index of the range must be decreased because the working list has been shortened from the front. We still want the sublist from the 0 index in the new working list, though.

Similarly, when `a` is not yet zero, the first element of the list is discarded, and `sublist` is called on the shortened working list; in this case *both* `a` and `b` must be decreased.

Note also that this code does no validation on the inputs; that is, this procedure assumes that valid input is provided. If `a` or `b` is out-of-range, or if `b` < `a`, there will be problems.

---

## A Solution Using Built-in List Procedures

---

Another approach could use the built-in procedures `list-tail` and `reverse`. First, an auxiliary procedure will be useful:

```
(define (dropr xs n)
  (reverse (list-tail (reverse xs) n)))
```

This procedure removes the rightmost `n` elements from an input list. Note that the built-in `list-tail` procedure returns its input list with the first `k` elements removed.

Now `dropr` and `list-tail` can be combined to make `sublist-2`:

```
(define (sublist-2 xs a b)
  (list-tail (dropr xs (- (length xs) b)) a))
```

Here, `list-tail` drops the first `a` elements of the input list, and `dropr` drops the last `l-b` elements from the list, where `l` is the length of the list.

Output is as before:

```
> (sublist-2 '(1 2 3 4 5 6) 1 3)
(2 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

In [guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/List-Selection.html) there are two built-in functions, `list-head` and `list-tail`. You could use them as in

```
(list-head (list-tail lst start) (- end start))
```

So,

```
(list-head (list-tail '(1 2 3 4 5) 1) (- 3 1))
```

results in `'(2 3)`

Obviously you will get an error if the parameters don't make sense.

As a function:

```
(define (sublist lst start end)
    (list-head (list-tail lst start) (- end start)))
```